# CMMotionManager detecting when the device is standing still

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-motion

How to setup the handling so i can detect when the device is standing still (in some threshold)

the code below isn't working as expected (the userAcceleration is just grater, depending on the device orientation, and the user even doesn't move the device (this value possibly comes from the gravity))

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
        self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1/2.0;
        [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {

            float accelerationThreshold = 0.75;
            CMAcceleration userAcceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration;
            if ((fabs(userAcceleration.x) > accelerationThreshold)
                || (fabs(userAcceleration.y) > accelerationThreshold)
                || (fabs(userAcceleration.z) > accelerationThreshold)) {
                self.deviceMoved = YES;
            } else {
                self.deviceMoved = NO;
            }

        }];
```

Answer (score 1):

needed to use the startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue

```
if (self.motionManager == nil) {
        self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
        self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1/2.0;
        [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {

            float accelerationThreshold = 0.25;
            CMAcceleration userAcceleration = motion.userAcceleration;
            if ((fabs(userAcceleration.x) > accelerationThreshold)
                || (fabs(userAcceleration.y) > accelerationThreshold)
                || (fabs(userAcceleration.z) > accelerationThreshold)) {
                self.deviceMoved = YES;
            } else {
                self.deviceMoved = NO;
            }

        }];
    }
```